# How to recover my data in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

By mistake I have not prefixed a Unicode string with `N` and I have inserted data that now contains `?` instead of the original Unicode characters. Using this as an example:

```
 SELECT T.A FROM ( SELECT '男孩 SQL' A) T
```

It is returning `?? SQL` instead of `男孩 SQL`.

So how can I get the actual value; what can I use in outer `SELECT` statement?

Comment: So your problem is that you're trying to insert and retrieve a Unicode character sequence via your SQL?

Comment: If you have inserted data into sql server table without `N` prefix and it is stored as `????` then you have lost your data, you will need to re-import the data again with N prefix.

Comment: This data is thrown away, and not logged anywhere. Sorry, your data is gone if it has already been inserted and you no longer have access to the original statements. Also, you can't magically fix the query in your question by changing the *outer* query. You need to add the `N` prefix to the *inner* query.

Comment: Ok, Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are declaring a hard coded `NVARCHAR` string value it is important to use this format:

```
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(10) = N'YourVariableHere'
```

Instead of :

```
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(10) = 'YourVariableHere'
```

The second method will cause an implicit column conversion which is at best bad for performance and at worst will incorrectly interperit the results. I just found a cool little test for this. Run this script in SQL Server.

```
SELECT N'௰', '௰';
```

You will get this as a result.

[image]

If you're interested in more information on Implicit Column Conversion look [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/implicit-conversion-costs).

However since you've already inserted this data into your database you are out of luck. There is no way to recover this unless you have the scripts saved somewhere else.

If you have the permissions and powers to insert data into a production system I suggest you exercise more caution next time.

Comment: I know that, But think I have added multiple records, without 'N', and Now u have only '??' in your table, So How u know the actual value of that

Comment: @VikasAhlawat you don't. that's the point. do it correctly the first time.